# Changing rootview in scenedelegate to a viewcontroller?

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I kind of messed up while building this app. Instead of using UIKit I used SwiftUI and now I have a view controller that I can't make into my root view. I was wondering if anyone could help this? Let me know, thanks. The strong text is where Im receiving the (Type 'ViewController.Type' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols) error.

```
   if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = **UIHostingController(rootView: ViewController)**
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need `window.rootViewController = ViewController()`.

Comment: Yep that worked thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For **SwiftUI**

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

For **Swift**

```
window.rootViewController = ViewController()
```